# PHP: $_GET value in constructor overridden by AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax

Here is my constructor:

```
function __construct(){
  $this->table_type = $_GET['page'];
}
```

When I try to access `$this->table_type` later with an AJAX call, the new $_GET values override what was set in the constructor and `$this->table_type` comes up null.

How to I grab the value of `$_GET['page']` as it is when the class is instantiated and not let it change?

Comment: You're probably looking for sessions.

Comment: Instead of teling us what you do - show us code how you do.

Comment: Get sure that the constructor is in the same file than the called file in the Browser

Comment: that's because every ajax call is a SEPARATE http request. if you don't include the query parameter each time, you'll just be writing accessing an undefined index, and writing `null` to the var.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you have your page loaded, the PHP has already been executed and the only result of that is the page you are seeing. No variables, nor classes, nor anything else is preserved. When the AJAX call occures, the whole PHP code is executed again.

If you want to preserve some data, use session.

Comment: I think the problem is that my class variable `$this->table_type` is just an alias for `$_GET['page']` so if `$_GET['page']` changes, so does `$this->table_type`. All I want to do it copy the value of `$_GET['page']` and have that never change.

Comment: What do you mean by _never_?

Comment: I start with `$_GET['page'] = 10`. Then I set `$var = $_GET['page']`. Then I change `$_GET['page'] = 20`. But I still want `echo $var` to yield `10`. Instead, it yields `20`.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer - in the time, when the AJAX call is being performed, your original `$var` doesn't exist. If you want to preserve it between the original load of page and the AJAX calls, you need to use sessions. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) is a nice tutorial.